# NSIS - CreateDirectory while compile time

Tags: time, compilation, directory, nsis

I am creatining a .ini-file while compile time (with NSIS).

```
!tempfile "${HKSTempPath}\NIC_HKSCommonUDF.ini"
!appendfile "${HKSTempPath}\NIC_HKSCommonUDF.ini" "[General]$\n"
```

The problem is, that the Directory doesnt exists and i cant call CreateDirectory outside functions, etc.

How can i create the directory?

Sorry for the stupid question. I have found an easy solution:

```
!system 'mkdir "${HKSTempPath}"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!system 'mkdir "${HKSTempPath}"'
```